# Webdriverio test on electron app not working after upgrading electron version to 26 (session not starting)

Tags: webdriver-io

We recently updated our Electron app to version 26.6.1 and since then, our automated tests have stopped working. The app does not open. We have tried upgrading the chromedriver and updating the "@WIDO" version in the package.json file to 8.26.2. Can you suggest any other solutions?